# Element doesn't get removed from the list of class type

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of class Type where i add all the objects of that class. But when i am trying to remove specific item from that list, the count in the list remains constant.
below is my code:-

```
var cgd = this.ContactGroupDetails.Where(a => a.ContactGroupID == (long)_ContactsIdentifier && a.ToDate == null).FirstOrDefault();
if (cgd != null)
{
  cgd.ToDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
  if (cgd.FromDate.GetValueOrDefault().Date == cgd.ToDate.GetValueOrDefault().Date)
  {
     this.ContactGroupDetails.Remove(cgd);
     cgd.MarkDelete();// to delete object from database
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you specifying which item to remove and from which list, the cgd or this.ContractGroupDetails? Either way, I suspect this belongs on SO more than Programmers SE.

Comment: @JBKing cgd is an object which i want to remove from the collection i.e., this.contactgroupdetails

Comment: Are you sure you are checking a count and not a capacity of the list?

Comment: Are you sure cgd is actually an element in the list?

Comment: @JBKing Yes, i have put a not null check, it contains that element thats why it retrieves the value from the list, isn't that obvious?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Sorry i know what a count is, but i don't know the difference between count and capacity

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma Well, then I guess you check `Count`. Or is it the `Capacity` property? A capacity is a size of a list's inner array and it says nothing about a number of items in the list but that there is no more than the current capacity.

Comment: If cgd is getting the default value which isn't in the list then there is nothing to remove is the case you have to worry about. cgd isn't null because it holds a default value which may not necessarily be an element in the list I'm thinking.

Comment: @JBKing No, it retrieves the value properly, i haven't checked it during debugging.